# How to sort fields in all json's according swagger

Tags: java, json

I have a lot of JSON files as test data for testing and I would like to sort fields in each JSON according to the JSON scheme from swagger.yml of the application. As you understand each could contain different set of fields

I use Java and Maven

I've tried to search Google and I've tried to read documentation Jackson but I've found anything that would help me

Comment: Why? The [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) states: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." No program should depend on the order. If this is for humans, it may make sense but any editor / tool could change that manual order again. That said, your best call is probably to write a small program and do that ordering for you. Post that program's code when you run into problems. See also [ask].

Comment: Yes, it's for humans)) Just for the best view and easier to change it manually) Ok, thanks, I'll try it. Do u have suggestions on how to do it?)